# Not able to access mirth connect installed on CentOs from windows machine

Tags: windows, centos, mirth

I have installed mirth connect on Cent Os machine.I can open mirth on same machine but when i try to open it from windows machine using browser i got "not able to open".

On Cent Os:-
firewall is disabled .I have checked using 'getenforce' and it is disabled.
I can ping my windows machine.

On windows:-
I can ping Cent Os machine.
but not able to open mirth connect u sing google chrome with port 8080.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Actually it was due to multiple jdk's installed on cantos. as on starting of mirth connect .mirth not able to identifies which jdk should use to access connector class..